# AWS CDK: Resource Policies are not being granted for Lambda Version

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I've a lambda version for which I want to grant invoke access to API gateway method. CDK is able to create resource policy to api-gateway when I am calling add_permission method on the actual function but not the function version. Is there something I am doing wrong?

- CDK version: 1.34.1
- Python: 3.7
- OS: Mac Mojave 10.14.6

Able to create Resource policy and endpoint works

```
       weatherHandler.add_permission(id='apigrantWeatherFnInvoke',principal=iam.ServicePrincipal(service='apigateway.amazonaws.com'),
    action='lambda:InvokeFunction',source_arn=api.arn_for_execute_api(method='GET',path='/',stage='dev')
    )
```

Not able to create Resource policy and end point is giving 500 Insufficient Privileges to invoke lambda

```
    weatherFuncStageVersion.add_permission(id='apigrantWeatherFnInvoke',principal=iam.ServicePrincipal(service='apigateway.amazonaws.com'),
    action='lambda:InvokeFunction',source_arn=api.arn_for_execute_api(method='GET',path='/',stage='dev')
    )
```

cdk diff is not showing any policy creation
cdk deploy  - no changes

Comment: Turns out it's a bug in CDK- I've created an issue for this https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/7588