# AWS CDK: Lambda resource based policy for a function with an alias

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

I am using CDK to create a lambda, a new version of the lambda, and point the "live" alias to the newest version of the lambda like so

```js
        const func = new lambda.Function(this, 'lambdaName', {
            // Other properties 
            description: `Generated on: ${new Date().toISOString()}`,
        });

        const version = func.addVersion(new Date().toISOString());

        const alias = new lambda.Alias(this, 'lambdaName-alias', {
            aliasName: 'live',
            version: version,
        });
```

Now, I want to add resource based permission to the alias `live` and not just the main lambda function.

I assumed that this would work but it doesn't create any resource based permissions at all:

```js
     alias.addPermission('CrossAccountAccessId', {
       action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction',
       principal: new ArnPrincipal('ACOUNT_NUMBER_XXX')
     });
```

How to add permissions to an alias using AWS CDK?

I referred to this for resource based alias permission-ing:     https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-aliases.html#versioning-permissions-alias

For the CDK docs, I read this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda.Alias.html#addwbrpermissionid-permission

I think it might be related to a bug in AWS CDK where adding resource based policy on a lambda version fails as mentioned here: [AWS CDK: Resource Policies are not being granted for Lambda Version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61401141/8656417) but I'm not sure if aliases also have the same problem as that of versions.

Comment: I did and none of them solved the problem I was facing.  
I've added my own answer to the question which helped me solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the other answers however, I did not see the Alias permission being created under the template tab of the CFN stack.

I ended up using the CFN L1 primitive in the CDK code like this:

```
const cfnPermission = new lambda.CfnPermission(this, 'LambdaInvokeAccessRemote', {
            action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction',
            functionName: alias.functionName,
            principal: "ACCOUNT_NUMBER"
});
```

After that, I was able to see the alias based permission under the template tab of the CFN stack:

```
LambdaInvokeAccessRemote:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      FunctionName:
        Fn::Join:
          - ""
          - - Fn::Select:
                - 6
                - Fn::Split:
                    - ":"
                    - Ref: LambdaAlias273D1F4C
            - :live
      Principal: "ACCOUNT_NUMBER"
```

Answer (score 1):

The following generates the expected cross-account [lambda permission](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-permission.html) for the alias.  I use CDK v2, although the v1 will work, too.

The `addVersion` method [is deprecated](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-lambda.Function.html#addwbrversionname-codesha256-description-provisionedexecutions-asyncinvokeconfigspan-classapi-icon-api-icon-deprecated-titlethis-api-element-is-deprecated-its-use-is-not-recommended%EF%B8%8Fspan) and is removed completely in v2. *"Instead, use `this.currentVersion` to obtain a reference to a version resource that gets automatically recreated when the function configuration (or code) changes"*.

```js
const alias = func.currentVersion.addAlias('live');

// `iam.ArnPrincipal` will work (cdk does not validate the format), but, `iam.AccountPrincipal` is semantically correct in your case.
const principal = new iam.AccountPrincipal('123456789012');
```

These 3 permission methods [are equivalent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda.Permission.html#example):

```js
this.alias.grantInvoke(principal);

this.alias.addPermission('CrossAccountPermission', { principal });

this.alias.addPermission('CrossAccountPermission', {
  action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction', // this is the default value
  principal,
});
```

The permission is created as expected. This test passes with any of the above 3 methods:

```js
// MyStack.test.ts
const cfnAlias = stack.alias.node.defaultChild as lambda.CfnAlias;

template.hasResourceProperties('AWS::Lambda::Permission', {
  Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction',
  FunctionName: { Ref: stack.resolve(cfnAlias.logicalId) },
  Principal: '123456789012',
});
```

Comment: How did you test it?  
Did you try to actually make a call from the other AWS account with the live alias?  
I checked the permissions under the lambda configurations tab and I don't see any permissions added to the live alias

Comment: @PodGen4 My answer uses the CDK's [Testing Constructs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/testing.html) to assert the permission's presence in the CloudFormation template.  You can check manually whether CDK did its bit: search the stack's `.template.json` (in `cdk.out`) for a `AWS::Lambda::Permission` Resource.  This testing happens before deploying.

Comment: @PodGen4  Once the stack is deployed, the `AWS::Lambda::Permission` resource should be listed in the CloudFormation console (Stacks > Resources).  In the Lambda console, first select the Alias (check that `> Alias:live` is the breadcrumbs).  The permission should be listed in the resource-based policy section.

Comment: I did not use the CDK's testing Constructs but rather, I deployed to the AWS account directly. And using this this.alias.addPermission(...) did not create an Alias permission in the CFN stack. 
I checked the output tab for the relevant CFN stack and couldn't find the alias based permission.